# Change color after click on TouchableHighlight in react native

Tags: react-native

I have done a many research on the color change after press/click. Finally
I got this script for change the state and put it in the TouchableHighlight. But When i clicked on that, only the "underlayColor={'gray'}" is working. Can i get some idea ?

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBar ,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableHighlight,
  PropTypes,
  Image,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import Form from '../components/Front';

import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class Login extends Component<{}> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataSource: {},
      pressed: false
    };
  }

  izijackpotconfirm() {
      Actions.izijackpotconfirm()
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var that = this;
    let items = Array.apply(null, Array(25)).map((v, i) => {
      return { id: i+1 };
    });
    that.setState({
      dataSource: items,
    });
  }
 static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Izi Jackpot",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#354247"
    },
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  };
    render() {

    var jackpotNumbers = [];
    let btn_class = this.state.black ? "NormalSet" : "SelectedSet";

        return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.middlecontainer}>
          <Text style={styles.logoText}>Please Select 5 Numbers and Submit</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', margin: 1 }}>
            <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {  Alert.alert(this.state.pressed) }}
                style={[
                    styles.iziPizi,
                    this.state.pressed ? { backgroundColor: "blue" } : {}
                ]}
                onHideUnderlay={() => {
                    this.setState({ pressed: false });
                }}
                onShowUnderlay={() => {
                    this.setState({ pressed: true });
                }}

                underlayColor={'gray'}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{ item.id}</Text></TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          )}
          //Setting the number of column
          numColumns={5}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />

        <View style={styles.middlecontainer}>
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.izijackpotconfirm} >
           <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>     
        </View>
      </View>

            )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    backgroundColor:'#6F9000',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 30,

  },
  middlecontainer: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent :'center',
    flex:1    
  },
  signupTextCont : {
    flexGrow: 1,
    alignItems:'flex-end',
    justifyContent :'center',
    paddingVertical:16,
    flexDirection:'row'
  },
  signupText: {
    color:'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
    fontSize:16
  },
  signupButton: {
    color:'#ffffff',
    fontSize:16,
    fontWeight:'500'
  },
  iziPizi: {
    width: 55,
    padding: 15,
    margin: 5,

    borderRadius: 80,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
    flex:1
  },
  iziPiziPress: {
    width: 55,
    padding: 15,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor:'#1c313a',
    borderRadius: 80,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
    flex:1
  },
  button: {
    width:300,
    backgroundColor:'#1c313a',
     borderRadius: 25,
      marginVertical: 10,
      paddingVertical: 13
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize:16,
    fontWeight:'500',
    color:'#ffffff',
    textAlign:'center'
  },
  logoText : {
    color:'#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  },
  imageThumbnail: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 100,
  },
});
```

One more thing to say that, i have used FlatList here. Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes. there was a **problem in FlatList**. but i dont know what is its problem.
use `ListItem` of `native-base` instead.
remember that if you want to use ListItem, in constructor change

```
this.state = {
          dataSource: {}, 
          ...
}
```

to

```
this.state = {
      dataSource: [],
}
```

use array insead. here is a sample code for you.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', margin: 1 }}>

    <List>
      {this.state.dataSource.map( item => 
      <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => {}}

            onShowUnderlay={this.onPress.bind(this)}
        >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{ item.id}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </ListItem> )
      }
    </List>
</View>
```

Also define onPress method.
another problem in your code is this that you `setState` of `pressed`.
it results that **all of your element** style will be changed. so all of your button `backgroundColor` will be changed.
so you must define `pressed` flag f**or every element** in your array and change this flag

Comment: But, l need the column like 1 to 25 and each line 5 numbers.

Comment: you can just do this by some styles simply

Comment: can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you work with the styles inside the Touchable. My advice is to create 2 styles that contain the changes:

```
  style={
      this.state.pressed ? styles.pressed : styles.iziPizi
  }
```

Inside the touchable of course:

```
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={() => {  Alert.alert(this.state.pressed) }}
  style={
      this.state.pressed ? styles.pressed : styles.iziPizi
  }
  onHideUnderlay={() => {
      this.setState({ pressed: false });
  }}
  onShowUnderlay={() => {
      this.setState({ pressed: true });
  }}
  underlayColor={'gray'}
>
```